# Filter function for range sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, filter

I have a dateset like this:

```
[
  { "gainLossPercent": -4.97 },
  { "gainLossPercent": -2.97 },
  { "gainLossPercent":  6.75 },
  { "gainLossPercent":  1.25 },
  { "gainLossPercent":  0.26 },
  { "gainLossPercent": -1.11 },
  { "gainLossPercent":  0.58 },
  { "gainLossPercent":  0.78 },
  { "gainLossPercent": -3.21 },
  { "gainLossPercent": -1.24 }
]
```

This data is from my state named as filteredData.
Now I want to do the range sorting by which user will provide the 2 range and then on filteredData array, only the matched condition will preserve and rest other values should filterout from an array.
For that I have made the logic in which I am using the filter function. Problem is it does not properly return the range If user choose 1 negative and other positive value and vice versa. Currently it will be perfectly fine on the two positive integers.
Below is my code:

```
//this.state.singleInput = User first input
//this.state.doubleInput = User second input
// In frontend I have 2 input fields. user will put the range with the help of these two fields
let sortData = filteredData;
let newFilter = sortData.filter(x => {
        if (String(this.state.singleInput) < '0') {
          if (String(x.gainLossPercent) >= 0) {
            if (String(x.gainLossPercent) >= String(this.state.singleInput) && String(x.gainLossPercent) <= String(this.state.doubleInput)) {
              return true;
      }
    } else if (String(x.gainLossPercent) <= 0) {
            if (String(x.gainLossPercent) <= String(this.state.singleInput) && String(x.gainLossPercent) <= String(this.state.doubleInput)) {
              return true;
      }
    }
  } else {
          if (String(x.gainLossPercent) >= String(this.state.singleInput) && String(x.gainLossPercent) <= String(this.state.doubleInput)) {
            return true;
    }
  }
```

Any help or suggestion is really appreciated. Thanks in advance for the inputs and interaction

Comment: Why are you insisting on comparing strings? Why not convert the user input to numbers and compare those with the values in the array instead?

Comment: please add some example of data various inputs and wanted outputs from data.

Comment: @Unmitigated yes I have tried and it works. I don't know why I have chosen the type String over Number.
Anyways thanks for the input. Really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Problem identified.
Data will be mismatched due to string conversion.

```
let newFilter = sortData.filter(x => {
        if (Number(x.gainLossPercent) >= Number(this.state.singleInput) && Number(x.gainLossPercent) <= Number(this.state.doubleInput)) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      })
```

Comment: come on, a value which is already a number shlould not converted to number. btw, whot is with the other problem of input with mixed ranges?

Comment: @NinaScholz I have not shared the full code. I have debugged that somewhere got the string under the loop iteration that is why for seamless, I have converted to string.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want lexicographical string comparison here.
Convert the user input to numbers first to perform numerical comparison. (This can be done with the unary plus operator.)

```js
sortData.filter(x => x.gainLossPercent >= +this.state.singleInput 
                        && x.gainLossPercent <= +this.state.doubleInput);
```